# Derivation of Noether's theorem by Gateaux derivative

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Noether's theorem states that if:

$$\ \int_{a}^{b} F(x, y, y') \,dx  = \ \int_{a_{new}}^{b_{new}} F(x_{new}, y_{new}, y_{new}') \,dx_{new} $$

for any $a$, $b$ and $y(x)$, and when $x$ and $x_{new}$ and $y$ and $y_{new}$ are of transformations:

$$x_{new} = \Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon)$$

$$y_{new} = \Psi(x, y, y', \epsilon)$$

$$x = \Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon = 0)$$

$$y = \Psi(x, y, y', \epsilon = 0)$$

$\epsilon$ is a variable scalar parameter, and if $y^*(x)$ is an extremal of the functional $\ \int_{a}^{b} F(x, y, y') \,dx$, meaning that $y^*(x)$ satisfies:

$$\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^*} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}}$$

then there is

$$\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}} \psi(x, y^*, y^{*'}) + (F(x, y^*, y^{*'}) - y^{*'}\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}})\phi(x, y^*, y^{*'}) = \text{constant},$$ with

$$\phi(x, y, y') = \frac{\partial \Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}\vert{_{\epsilon = 0}}$$

$$\psi(x, y, y') = \frac{\partial \Psi(x, y, y', \epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}\vert{_{\epsilon = 0}}.$$

My question is: is it possible to derive

$$\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}} \psi(x, y^*, y^{*'}) + (F(x, y^*, y^{*'}) - y^{*'}\frac{\partial F(x, y^*, y^{*'})}{\partial y^{*'}})\phi(x, y^*, y^{*'}) = \text{constant}$$

from

$$\frac{d{\ \int_{a_{new}}^{b_{new}} F(x_{new}, y_{new}, y_{new}') \,dx_{new} }}{d\epsilon}\vert{_{\epsilon = 0}}~?$$

I read some proof for example, https://drchristianphsalas.com/2020/08/06/proving-noethers-theorem/, but I don't understand the procedures such as ignoring the high order terms, so that only the linear part is used, bla bla.... I want to know if it is possible to only use total derivatives and/or partial derivatives to derive the equations. I tried to do it, but the Gateaux derivative

$$\frac{d{\ \int_{a_{new}}^{b_{new}} F(x_{new}, y_{new}, y_{new}') \,dx_{new} }}{d\epsilon}\vert{_{\epsilon = 0}}$$

becomes a mess after I substitute $x_{new}$ with $\Phi(x, y, y', \epsilon)$ and substitute $y_{new}$ with $\Psi(x, y, y', \epsilon)$. I don't know what to do next from this messy derivative.

Could you demonstrate that derivation if yo think it's possible to reach Noether's result by Gateaux derivative without using the trick of ignoring the high order terms of $\epsilon$?